# In visual studio 2005 build mode drop down, release mode not shown

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

Recently I got a project when after opening in visual studio 2005 in build mode drop down, only debug mode is shown but release mode not shown.Project builds successfully in debug mode is there a way to enable release mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right click on the solution file and select "Configuration Manager" there you can set the build for all projects, or project by project.

If the configuration manager you can also add different configurations, including a release version.

Comment: When i click and go to Configuration Manager and click new configuration under copy from configuration drop down release mode is not shown

Comment: You can create it, it is just compiling all projects in release mode and not debug.